# How to add intake vent to an attic of a hip roof without any eves?

Tags: roof, ventilation

My house has a hip roof with no gables or eaves. We have a ridge vent but no intakes. I'd like to install intakes to improve air flow and ventilation. I've seen a lot of on-roof vent products but they all phrasing like this in the product description

> Roof louvers are a type of attic **exhaust** vent that make up half of a balanced attic ventilation system for each roof. **Intake** vents make up the other half of the system.

I haven't found anything other than soffit, gable, or drip edge vents. Drip edge vents seem like the only option I could install on my roof but that looks like something I could only install easily while replacing the roof.

Is there an easy way to retrofit intake vents for my my gable-less soffit-less roof?

Comment: You can use standard roof vents as intake vents if they are lower than your ridge air will be pulled into them.  When neighbor fire separation is an issue - they don't want fire sucked into soffit intake - they make you install standard vents a little farther away than the soffit.  The fire code is probably more about delaying the fire being pulled into the attic than completely preventing it.

Comment: Are you looking for something like this [deck air](https://www.lomanco.com/vents/intake-vents) vent?

Comment: I think I'm more interested in @FreshCodemonger's suggestion of using 'exaust' products as intakes - assuming that's effective.

The shingle-under products like that deck-air seem like a lot to install myself